# Reload Scenario in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, page-refresh

I am currently working on a mobile app..where I am fetching a response from a REST GET call.

Every thing is perfect. But , I want expert suggestion on how to re-render this data if user reloads the page.. or what is the best way to handle this scenario. Caching / storage won't help me here as this is sensitive data.

Need expert opinion please?

Comment: What triggers the reload?  The user clicking the refresh button in the browser?  Or a refresh button on the view?  Can you be more specific about what your needs are, too?  Is performance the concern?

Comment: **browser reload** .. from a performance point of view , I want to ensure that, there should not be un-necessary hit to server if user reloads the page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider [session storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).  It will persist only as long as the current session is active (until tab or window is closed), and you can certainly think of additional security strategies, such as encryption and expiration.

Build an AngularJS service for your data source which will first query the session storage as a cache, before bothering your servers.  I'd recommend creating a service that wraps session storage itself - maybe call it a ThingCache - that would be injected into the main data service.